# Make command not recognized when script is called through crontab

Tags: makefile, cron, sh

**So while running the shell script as ./myscript.sh or bash myscript.sh the make command is recognized, but while putting the same thing in crontab the make command is not recognized. How to resolve this?**

myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/somya/make_design && make all ;

crontab -e ;
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/home/somya
*/1 * * * * /home/somya/myscript.sh > /home/somya/error2.log 2>&1 ;
```

error.log
 /home/somya/myscript.sh: line 1: make: command not found

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Answer (score 0):

Use full path of the make i.e., */usr/bin/make*